# What exactly is a ROM?

Tags: android

I began studying android and became curious what is a ROM. There are many pages that offer to download ROMs but what it is exactly from a developer's point of view is not quite clear.

So what is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ROM in this context is a nickname for the operating system software that gets installed into the Read Only Memory (ROM) area of the phone.

Check out [this page](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/01/custom-roms-for-android-explained-and-why-you-want-them/) for a more thorough description.

Comment: I hope this answered your question, it was a little vague, so I grabbed something that described a few different aspect of ROMs - Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In the Android world, a ROM is a modified version of the Android OS that can be run on a rooted phone. There are generally 3 types of ROMs: one that emulates an upcoming release of Android, one that adds more features not seen in Android OS, and one that focuses on speed and stability.

You can find more information on Android ROMs [here](http://lifehacker.com/5596108/how-to-choose-the-right-android-rom-for-you).

Answer (score 0):

ROM is nothing but the Android OS. We use Stock ROM in our device which comes by default by the company we cannot modify the stock ROM but we can modify Custom ROM which gives easy modifications of the OS with various tweks you can fine more information [here](http://www.geekypajis.com/2017/07/how-to-flash-custom-rom.html)